# How can one find all ideals of $ (\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z)[x]/(x^3)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am working on Homework Problem which asks me to find all nontrivial ideals of the ring
$ R = S[x]/J$  where`$ S = \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$  and $ J =  (x^3)$.
I could construct a homomorphism from  $ R = S[x]/J$ to $ [(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)[x]/J]\times [(\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)[x]/J] $. However, I cannot go further...What should I do?

Comment: S = $6Z$ and other part, I should use 3 instead of 2

Comment: $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)[x]$ is a principal ideal ring. Do a search for ideal correspondence in the quotient ring.  These basic principles say that the ideals of the quotient correpond to the divisors of $x^3$.

Comment: I see what you were doing now. Didn't notice that was a product.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1989335/29335)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** (a general procedure to find all the ideals in a finite ring): First, find all the distinct principal ideals. Then for each $n$, find all distinct ideals generated by at most $n$ elements (by looking at the sums $I+J$, where $I$ is principal and $J$ is generated by at most $n-1$ elements). Since your ring has $6^3$ elements, after at most $6^3$ steps you will not get any new ideals (likely, much sooner).

Comment: My apologies to readers: the original question *title* was about finding all ideals in a finite ring. Since this did not match the question contents, I made it closer to the body question, but it looks like this solution was very close temporally with my edit. This is good advice for the general case. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

$(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)[x]$ is a prinicipal ideal domain when $p$ is prime, so the ideals of the quotient by $(x^3)$ will correspond to divisors of $x^3$.

There are four (classes of) divisors: $\{1, x, x^2, x^3\}$, so there are four ideals in each half of your product.

Combining them in pairs, you get the ideals of the product, which you already related to your original ring.  Writing out all 16 possibilities probably isn't hard, but I leave it to you to translate this back to your original ring as an exercise.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not understand the so the ideals of the quotient by $(x^3)$ will correspond to divisors of $x^3$... Can you explain more? Or, am I missing some Theorems? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @kaimaru I just told you the theorems: 1) $F[x]$ is a principal ideal domain when $F$ is a field, and 2), the ideals of $F[x]/J$ correspond to ideals of $F[x]$ containing $J$.  PUtting these together you get: the ideals of $F[x]/(a)$ correspond to divisors of $a$.  This is because $(a)\supseteq (b)$ means $a|b$ in PIDs.

Comment: It probably appears here somewhere, but so far the solutions I've found have been like mine, because the two theorems are so basic.

Answer (score 0):

The ideals of $R$ are into 1-1 correspondence with ideals of $S[x]$ containing $x^3$.

Now, as you noticed, $S\simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]\times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a product of two principal rings, so it is a principal ring (since the ideals of a direct product ring is a direct  product of ideals).

A principal ideal $(f)$ of $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}[x]$ contains $x^3$ if and only if $f\mid x^3$. Since you work up to units, you may assume that $f$ is monic. You get $f=1,x,x^2,x^3$. Finally you will get four ideals: $R, (x), (x^2), (x^3)=(0).$

Comment: No, this is not correct. There are more than four ideals.  The ideal $(3)$ contains four ideals, and the ideal $(4)$ contains four different ideals, and $(3)\oplus(4) = R$.  In a domain you can work up to units, but this is not a domain. You need to work using both units *and* idempotents.

Comment: Maybe to make it even more obvious, $(x)=(3x)\oplus (4x)$, for starters.